# Table is geting distorted when freezing columns in datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using a Jquery datatable. The data for teh table is dynamically shown. I want to freeze the first 2 columns in the datatable. But the table is getting distorted when I add the code to freeze columns.

```
  $('#example1').dataTable({
                        data:data.data,
                        columns:data.columns,
                        paging:         false,
                        scrollX:       true,
                        scrollY:false,  
                         scrollCollapse: true,
                        fixedColumns:   {
                            leftColumns: 2
                        },
                        "columnDefs": [ {
                            "targets": colStyleArray,
                            "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                            //  console.log("td"+td+"cellData"+cellData+"rowData"+rowData+"row"+row+"col"+col);
                              if ( colStyleArray.indexOf(col)!=-1 ) {
                                $(td).addClass("bg-info")
                              }
                            }
                          } ]
                          
                    });
```

Actual Result (After Using Fixed Columns):

[image]

Result comes like this If I don't use the Fixed columns code :

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by freeze the first 2 columns? You mean they stay fixed on scroll?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy yes

Comment: it works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zavk8s0w/)